# Limit duration of video to 5 seconds in Ionic5

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, plugins, mediacapture

I am using media capture ionic 5 plugin. Using the `captureVideo` function I want to limit the duration of a video to 5 seconds. I am passing `duration` in the options but it is not working in Android 13. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
let options = { limit: 1, duration: 5, quality: 0.5 };
this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options).then()
```

Why duration not working in android 13

```
let options = { limit: 1, quality: 0.5 };
this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(
```